Android post request does not have application/json body
I m training with http request via android client and a server, using Okhttp3 module. I already used get request with no problems, but when I try post request they don't reach the server.
Using some Log.d I verified is not in the correct format and that the server ask for application/json body, but to me it looks like I m doing everything correctly. I turned on the option
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

in the manifest to avoid being blocked for lack of encryption.
I also tried enqueue() method instead of execute() for async method of post request, but it didn't work anyway, I don't get why I should send my request in sync way since I don't need it to, so I switched back
Here s the code
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put("user", "IP-Alby");
                    jsonObject.put("password", "blabla");

                    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(
                            jsonObject.toString(),
                            MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8")
                    );

                    Log.d("NetworkRequest", "request created");
                    Request postRequest = new Request.Builder().url("http://x.x.x.x:25565/api/register").post(requestBody).build();
                    Response response = client.newCall(postRequest).execute();
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                    Log.d("NetworkRequest", "status code: "+statusCode);
                    String responseBody = response.body().string();
                    Log.d("NetworkRequest", "Response Body: " + responseBody);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("NetworkRequest", "POST was correct");
                        String responseBody2 = response.body().string();
                        Log.d("NetworkRequest", responseBody2);
                    }
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.e("NetworkRequest", "something went wrong");
                    }

and this is the filtered LogCat response I get
D  request created
D  status code: 400
D  Response Body: Expected application/json content type
E  something went wrong


If you notice, it doesn't trigger response.isSuccesful()
I would avoid considering url typo because I already tested it in other way, and it worked, it's just on this app its giving me headache.
Any help? The body content is formatted correctly right?
Added on 19/09
I'm adding info about the server, thats in javascript
    const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400'); // Cache CORS preflight per 24 ore
    
    const pathName= req.url;
    
    if (pathName === "/home") { //open a test page that show the content of file example.txt
        console.log("home reacehd");
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain'); 
        res.end(example);
    } 
    else if (pathName === '/api/register') { //save data locally
        console.log("a request has reached this path");
        if(req.method === 'POST'){
            handlePostRequest(req, res, async (body) => {
            const { username, password } = body;
            users.push({username, password});
            console.log("Username:", username);
            console.log("Password:", password);
            //updateDatabase(users);
            sendJsonResponse(res, 200, { message: 'Register op was succesfull'});
            });
        } else {
        console.log("not format POST");
        }
    } 


the request reach the path to the point it triggers the method handlePostRequest(), this is how is it looks:

    function handlePostRequest(req, res, callback) {
            let body = '';
        req.on('data', chunk => {
            body += chunk.toString(); // Convert buffer into stirng
        });
        req.on('end', () => {
            if (req.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
                try {
                    const parsedBody = JSON.parse(body); // Parse the body as JSON
                    callback(parsedBody);
                } catch (error) {
                    res.statusCode = 400; // Bad Request
                    res.end('Invalid JSON');
                }
            } else {
                res.statusCode = 400; // Bad Request
                res.end('Expected application/json content type');
            }
        });
    }


it doesnt go past the control:

    if (req.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json')


Can the problem be Media.Type declaration on the android app?

Based on this error: Response Body: Expected application/json content type
I assume your request requires this defined in the header of the request. This specific header would need to be added to the postRequest object. Try replacing your postRequest builder with this:
Request postRequest = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://x.x.x.x:25565/api/register")
        .post(requestBody)
        .headers(new Headers.Builder()
                .add("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build())
        .build();

Its been a while since I wrote Java code, but I assume thats correct. The point here is to ensure you add the correct headers to the Request.Builder().

I tried to add a header check like u said but it doesn't resolve the problem. Maybe I m lacking other type of control to understand where s the problem but I m sure you are on the right direction. I changed and added my post with information I checked after your sugguestion
This is a fragment of my server, the request trigger the path and the req.method==post, enters the function that hadle Post request, but when it check for header application/json it skip that part and launch the error I ve shown to you
